# Is glEnable obsolete/unneeded in OpenGL ES 2?

Tags: opengl, ios

In an iOS app I am writing I am now culling all the GL 1 crap from my GL 2 code. Can I safely remove `glEnable`?

Comment: glEnable() is usually used with parameters - see http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glEnable.html - could you please tell us what you plan to use/are using glenable() for?

Comment: @sarahm, this is from the GLES 1.0 specs; the 2.0 version is at http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice I was quoting the old spec. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`glEnable` and `glDisable` are still present in GLES 2, but a lot of boolean states are deprecated or even removed (for instance, `GL_TEXTURE_2D` or `GL_ALPHA_TEST`).

According to [the manual page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml), the following boolean states can still be enabled or disabled using these functions:

- `GL_BLEND`
- `GL_CULL_FACE`
- `GL_DEPTH_TEST`
- `GL_DITHER`
- `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL`
- `GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE`
- `GL_SAMPLE_COVERAGE`
- `GL_SCISSOR_TEST`
- `GL_STENCIL_TEST`